# Get values of Property where the values are in a List

Tags: vb.net, list, class, properties

Google has failed me, and so I turn to Stack Overflow. You're my only hope!

I have a class that has several properties. One of the Properties is a List of doubles. I want to be able to read each double in the list and print them to a text box.

```
Public Class MyClass
    Dim aValue As List(Of Double)

    Public Property myProp As List(Of Double)

        Get
            Return aValue 'This very well could be my problem
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Double))
            'This is also likely the culprit, as I have no idea what to put here
        End Set

    End Property

End Class
```

So, I have that class. Then, I try to initialize the values of `myProp` as follows:

```
Dim c As New MyClass()

Dim vals As New List(Of Double)

    For i = 0 To 11
        Dim rndVal = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - (-10) + 1) * Rnd())) + (-10)
        vals.Add(rndVal)
    Next

c.myProp = vals
```

Then I want to be able to get the Property `myProp` and return the contained values of `myProp`, and then print them to a text box. Here's what I have currently:

```
Public Class Calc

    Private Sub drpdwnBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventARgs), Handles drpdwnBox.SelectedIndexChanged

        For Each p As Reflection.PropertyInfo In myClass.GetType().GetProperties()

            If p.CanRead Then

                'This works to get the name of the Property, but...
                txtBox.Text &= p.Name & " "

                'This does nothing, basically.
                If p.GetType Is GetType(List(Of Double)) Then

                    For Each k In p.GetValue(myClass, Nothing).Keys
                        txtBox.Text &= p.GetValue(myClass, Nothing).Keys.ToString() & " "
                        txtBox.Text &= vbNewLine
                    Next

                Else
                    'This also works to get the value of properties that aren't lists
                    txtBox.Text &= p.GetValue(Nation, Nothing).ToString() & vbNewLine

                End If

            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

There are likely to be several problems with the code above. At this point though, I'll take any help I can get. If there's a better way to do this without having a List as a Property, that would also be a welcome solution. The primary reason I'm using the List as a Property way of doing this is that I'm using XmlSerializer to quickly and easily convert classes and properties to an XML file for storage.

Anyway, the output I get when I run this code is as follows:

```
myProp
```

Aaaand that's it. No values of the List are added, but I at least get the name of the Property, so that part at least is correct.

Anyway, thank you to anyone who can provide any solution!

Comment: Just from looking at this I can see one problem: p.GetType will always return the type of PropertyInfo. Maybe you want p.Value.GetType.

Comment: Yep, you're totally right. I ended up using p.PropertyType to determine the type of the property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to have a `Set` at all for this property. Do it like this:

```
Public Class myClass
    Private aValue As New List(Of Double)

    Public Property myProp As List(Of Double)
        Get
            Return aValue 
        End Get    
    End Property

End Class
```

And then add values like this:

```
For i = 0 To 11
    Dim rndVal = CInt(Math.Floor((10 - (-10) + 1) * Rnd())) + (-10)
    'myProp.Add() only needs the Get accessor!
    myClassInstance.myProp.Add(rndVal)
Next
```

Notice I used `myClassInstance` instead of just `myClass`. In order to use your class, you have to actually create an instance of it in a variable. All of stuff from `Public Class myClass` all the way to `End Class` just describes how an object instance of the class will behave once you create one, but it has *not* actually created anything in memory yet that  you can use. Somewhere, you have to actually say `New myClass()` before you have anything you can work with.

Once you have that variable, your final code snippet will look more like this:

```
Private Sub drpdwnBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventARgs), Handles drpdwnBox.SelectedIndexChanged

    For Each k As Double In myClassInstance.myProp
        txtBox.Text &= k
    Next
End Sub
```

Until you are able to understand the difference between an instance of a class, and the definition for a class, and how to use variables with object references for your classes, you're gonna have a hard time writing any working code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to go too in-depth with the values bit since I was fairly sure that worked, but I do have `Dim c As myClass = New myClass` before the randomizer. I'll update my original question to reflect that and thanks for pointing that out.

Also, thank you so much for your help! I'll give this a shot, but from your past experience, I'm fairly sure this will work. ;)

Comment: In that case, `myClassInstance` can become `c` in most of my example code, but you'll need a way to reference the _same_ `c` in both sections.